# Инициализация массива размером Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2

Tags: java, массивы

Инициализирую в main массив.

```
int[] integers = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE-2];
```

Один элемент типа int - 4 байта, таких элементов 2147483645 и 4 байта под размер массива. 4 * 2147483645 + 4 = 8,6 гигабайт.
Я выделяю 10 гигабайт для VM -Xms10g -Xmx10g
и получаю исключение `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
Почему?

Comment: А у вас есть столько памяти?  А машина x64?

Comment: Машина x64, 8 гигабайт есть + использую файл подкачки, может проблема из за того, что я использую подкачку?

Comment: если выделить 13 гигабайт для VM всё работает(массив инициализируется), но я не могу понять, почему именно 13 + гигабайт нужно выделить, что бы инициализировать такой массив. Если я правильно расчитал в вопросе должно требоваться 8,6 гигабайт.

Comment: Подозреваю, что связано с организацией памяти для нужд GC (разделение кучи на пространство для новых и старых объектов). Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с [параметрами](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html) `-XX:NewRatio` и т.п.

Comment: @zRrr, точно, спасибо, буду эксперементировать

Answer (score 1):

Используя VisualVM сделайте heap dump, чтобы увидеть, как используется память.